# javaFX show correct value on button coordinates

Tags: javafx, fxml, actionevent

I've reduced the question to just the problem, so I'm making a UI for minesweeper game, in the controller below, in the StartGame method, things are well (according to my check using debug) until the line of

> game.open(x,y)

, meaning I manage to create the board and add buttons (which will act as the slots) to the GridPane, but my issue is that I can't seem to open and show the correct value on the slot. (the logics of Mines class works fine - the one without the javaFX part).

```
package MS;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBase;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NewGameCONTROLLER {
    Mines game;
    int rows, columns, mines;
    Button b;

    @FXML
    private TextField NumRows;

    @FXML
    private TextField NumCols;

    @FXML
    private TextField NumM;

    @FXML
    private Button StartGame;

    @FXML
    private Button BackMainMenu;

    @FXML
    private Button RandomGame;

    @FXML
    void BackMainMenu(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); // Create loading object
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MainMenuFXML.fxml")); // fxml location
        VBox root = loader.load(); // Load layout
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"file:///C:/EclipseProjects/MineSweeper/src/MS/menu.jpg\")");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); // Create scene with chosen layout
        Stage primaryStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        primaryStage.setTitle("..."); // Set stage's title
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(400); // Won't be allowed to make width/height smaller
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(350);
        primaryStage.setMaxWidth(600);
        primaryStage.setMaxHeight(450);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Set scene to stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Show stage
    }

    @FXML
    void RandomGame(ActionEvent event) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int low = 3, high = 15;
        int minesLow = 1, minesHigh;
        rows = rand.nextInt(high - low) + low;
        columns = rand.nextInt(high - low) + low;
        minesHigh = rows * columns - 1;
        mines = rand.nextInt(minesHigh - minesLow) + minesLow;
        game = new Mines(rows, columns, mines);
    }

    @FXML
    void StartGame(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        rows = Integer.parseInt(NumRows.getText());
        columns = Integer.parseInt(NumCols.getText());
        mines = Integer.parseInt(NumM.getText());
        game = new Mines(rows, columns, mines);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); // Create loading object
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("BoardFXML.fxml")); // fxml location

        AnchorPane root = loader.load(); // Load layout
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"file:///C:/EclipseProjects/MineSweeper/src/MS/Pic.jpg\")");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); // Create scene with chosen layout
        Stage gameStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        gameStage.setTitle("..."); // Set stage's title
        gameStage.setMinWidth(1000); // Won't be allowed to make width/height smaller
        gameStage.setMinHeight(500);
        gameStage.setMaxWidth(1200);
        gameStage.setMaxHeight(800);
        gameStage.setScene(scene); // Set scene to stage

        BoardCONTROLLER bCont = loader.getController(); // Prepare board in BoardCONTROLLER
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                b = new Button(" ");
                b.setMinSize(40, 40);
                b.setMaxSize(40, 40);
                bCont.TheBoard.add(b, i, j);
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < bCont.TheBoard.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            ((ButtonBase) bCont.TheBoard.getChildren().get(i)).setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    int x, y;
                    event.getSource();
                    x = (int) ((Button) event.getSource()).getProperties().get("gridpane-column");
                    y = (int) ((Button) event.getSource()).getProperties().get("gridpane-row");
                    game.open(x, y);
                    for (int i=0;i<game.getCol();i++)
                        for (int j=0;i<game.getRow();j++) {
                            if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1)=='T')
                                ((Button) bCont.TheBoard.getChildren().get(i)).setText(game.get(x, y));
                        }
                /*  while ()
                    for (int i = 0; i < bCont.TheBoard.getChildren().size(); i++) {
                        if (game.board[x][y].charAt(2) == 'B') {
                            ((Button) bCont.TheBoard.getChildren().get(i)).setText(game.get(x, y));
                        }
                    }*/
                }
            });
        }
        gameStage.show(); // Show stage
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: @matt done, hopefully it's more understandable now

Comment: Cool, it is much better. So it sounds like you get a click a button, and you need to check if that button has a bomb and "open" it if it doesn't. Are the correct values for x and y returned?

Comment: @matt yes, the x and y values are returned correctly (made sure and checked it in the debugger), the "game" variable (a Mines object) opens the correct slot (after "game.open(x,y)"), the "open" method will basically add a "T" char so the code opens that slot (the "T" is the indicator for the slot to be opened). And now for the issue, I can't seem to find a way to open it, I tried as shown in the loop but it is wrong since that slot already contains "T" so then it opens many other slots (which shouldn't be opened), I need to open only the correct slot (containing "T").

Comment: Why are you going through all of the slots though? Don't you already have the slot you want to change? `(Button)evt.getSource()` is the button you want to change?

Comment: @matt You're correct, but I couldn't do it. The double loop is incorrect since it doesn't get me to the specific button in the gridpane itself (bCont.TheBoard.getChildren().get(i)), somehow I need to get to the correct "i" of the correct button but I can't reach it..

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look at this loop.

```
for (int i=0;i<game.getCol();i++)
    for (int j=0;i<game.getRow();j++) {
        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1)=='T')
            ((Button) bCont.TheBoard.getChildren().get(i)).setText(game.get(x, y));
    }    
}
```

The variable `i` does not correspond to a row coordinate, it corresponds to the n'th child in the board. So really, your just looping through the all of the children in the first row (or first column).

On way I can see to fix that;

```
for( Node child: bCont.TheBoard.getChildren() ){
    int i = (int) ((Button) child).getProperties().get("gridpane-column");
    int j = (int) ((Button) child).getProperties().get("gridpane-row");
    if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1)=='T'){
        ((Button) child).setText(game.get(x, y));
    }
}
```

That way you go through all the children and check their status on the board.

I don't know if the order of the children nodes in GridPane correspond to the layout order, a common technique to pack a 2D array into a 1D array,

```
bCont.TheBoard.getChildren().get(i + j*game.getCol());
```

Remember you have row x col total buttons.

Comment: I just changed the if line to game.get(i,j) instead of (x,y) and it worked great (I assume it's because if the slot simply has a "T" it should be opened)! Thank you! Also your last note, I do know this, but never tried implementing it this way, very useful, thanks!